# How do i make my div square responsive to clicks

Tags: javascript, dom, events

```js
let container =
  document.getElementById('container');

function getGrid(gridNumber) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= gridNumber * gridNumber; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.style.border = '1px solid red'
    container.appendChild(row).classList.add('box');
  }
}

getGrid(16);
```

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.divcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <h1> Etch-a-Sketch </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="divcontainer">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

I am making a simple etech a sketch and so far i have created a grid of square divs. i need some direction on where to go from here. i think i need to attach keydown event listeners of each of the divs that i injected using javascript dom manipulation but how do i add event listeners to divs injected?

Comment: You can refer to [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) is the best solution for this. Instead of adding listeners to all the grid squares add *one* to the parent element and have that watch for events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM.

When the listener captures an event [it first checks to see](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches) if the element that triggered it is a box (it might have other child elements that aren't boxes that we want to ignore), and then it executes some code - in this case it toggles a `filled` class on the box.

(I've played around a little with your CSS in this expanded example, and renamed a couple of ids/classes in the HTML.)

```js
// Cache the grid element, and add a listener to it
const grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
grid.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function getGrid(gridNumber) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= gridNumber * gridNumber; i++) {
    const box = document.createElement('div');

    // Renamed the variable, and added the border
    // color to CSS instead
    box.classList.add('box');
    grid.appendChild(box);
  }
}

getGrid(16);

// When an element is clicked the listener (attached
// to the `.grid` parent element) checks that that
// it was a box, and then toggles a `filled` class on
// that clicked element
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.box')) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('filled');
  }
}
```

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(16, 1fr);
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box:hover { cursor: pointer; }
.box:hover:not(.filled) { background-color: red; opacity: 0.3; }

.filled { background-color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <h1> Etch-a-Sketch </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add event listeners to an HTMLElement at any time after you create it, as long as you keep a **reference** to it, in this case the variable `row`

```js
const row = document.createElement('div');
row.addEventListener('click', event=>{
    //... Reaction ...
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *event-delegation*. This means adding a single event listener that capture the events that bubble. In there check if the clicked element is the element you're expecting it to be.

```
const container = document.getElementById('container');

container.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const isbox = event.target.closest('.box') !== null;
  if (!isBox) {
    // Not a box, do nothing.
    return;
  }

  // Assert logic
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the behavior you want but you can add event on row directly (I've put a condition in case you want to 'uncolor' the selected box)

```js
let container =
  document.getElementById('container');

function getGrid(gridNumber) {
  for (let i = 1; i <= gridNumber * gridNumber; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.style.border = '1px solid red'
    container.appendChild(row).classList.add('box');

    row.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      if (row.style.background === 'green')
        row.style.background = 'none'
      else
        row.style.background = 'green'
    });
  }
}

getGrid(16);
```

```css
.banner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.divcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.box {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="banner-text">
    <h1> Etch-a-Sketch </h1>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="divcontainer">
  <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```